# How to type Logic Symbol in Pages?

Tags: macbook-pro, pages

How can I type logic symbol like "＆ - → ↔ " and so on in pages?

Comment: What version of pages? What OS? What version of that OS? Pages runs on iOS devices as well as OS X devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also import a file like this to [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html):

```
not,¬
or,∨
and,∧
l,←
r,→
lr,↔
ll,⇐
rr,⇒
iff,⇔
all,∀
some,∃
nsome,∄
neq,≠
xor,⊻
nand,⊼
nor,⊽
oplus,⊕
qed,∎
equiv,≡
top,⊤
bot,⊥
vdash,⊢
models,⊨
nmodels,⊭
```

I made a [text file for HTML5 entity names](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b7UnYrZU) based on http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/byalpha.html. Many of the abbreviations are the same as TeX / LaTeX character commands.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X Apple have whats called the "Character Palette" for inserting special characters such symbols, letters with accents, math references, Japanese characters etc..

You can find the Character Palette in the Input menu.

Go to System Preferences --> International. Click 'Input Menu'.

Click the checkboxes next to Character Palette and "Show Input menu in menu bar" (this will allow you to access it from the menu bar).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help,but I can't find"International" in"System preference".

Comment: what version of OS X are you using? International should be located in the first row of System Preferences (flag icon) underneath the 'Personal' section. May also be listed as 'Language & Text' depending on version.

Answer (score 1):

I find both [Mac Official Help](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6597?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and [this](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/10/access-mac-special-characters-with-the-character-viewer/).

Basically, just hitting Command+Option+T